# How to redirect a request, if PHP Module is turned-OFF in Apache

Tags: php

My web pages are written in PHP. If accidentally the PHP Module is turned OFF, then the requested page will simply display the source code. As a safety measure, is there any way to redirect the request to a different URL (as wanted), if PHP module is OFF. I mean something like:

***< IfModule     !php_module>
  ... stop & go to a different place,... things like that.
< / IfModule >***

Answer (score -1):

I:
 PHP.INI:

```
short_open_tag = On
```

II : apache config (httpd.con):

```
LoadModule php5_module "C:/php/php5apache2_2.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
PHPIniDir "C:/php"
```

III:
Make sure you are accessing your file over your webserver using an URL like http://localhost/file.php not via local file access file://localhost/www/file.php

IV: make sure your source is between